# manually control decision tree in weka

Tags: data-mining, weka, decision-tree

Month is an attribute in my dataset, which I believe is very important and I want it to be split first in j48. But by default, weka would choose other attribute to split first. Is there any way to control this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you are no longer doing J48.

You can hack around it, by splitting your data as desired on the month, then training J48 decision trees on the split data, and manually joining them on the month again.

But J48 / C4.5 is essentially *defined* by the rule it uses for finding the attribute to split on. By overriding this, you essentially stop using the J48/C4.5 algorithm and instead build manual decision trees.